# Two routes with different query strings for the same component

Tags: reactjs

I have created two `Route` for the same component called `UploadSubmission`:

```
<Route exact path='/student/upload-submission?reviewRoundId=:reviewRoundId' component={UploadSubmission} />
<Route exact path='/student/upload-submission?submissionId=:submissionId' component={UploadSubmission} />
```

Inside the `UploadSubmission` component, I want to show `Add` or `Edit` form to the user by checking the query strings returned, such as `props.match.params.reviewRound`.

However, the `path` set in the `Route` is somehow problematic since when navigated to the url `student/upload-submission?submissionId=1`, the component does not load.

I am not sure how to address this issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just have one route for the component and then inside the component get the values from the query string. Then you can render what you need based on that.

#### Example

Route

```
<Route exact path='/student/upload-submission' component={UploadSubmission} />
```

UploadSubmission.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'

const UploadSubmission = ({
  match: {
    params: {
      reviewRoundId = null,
      submissionId = null,
    },
  },
}) => {
  if(reviewRoundId) {
    return (
      <span>Review: {reviewRoundId}</span>
    )
  }

  return (
    <span>Submission: {submissionId}</span>
  )
}

export default withRouter(UploadSubmission)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But `path='/student/upload-submission'` does not pass any query strings?

Comment: The route will still show the component with or without query strings. You will have access to all query strings params through the `withRouter` function. You should not setup the route path prop to include query strings.